# How to merge Arrays having same keys only and neglect different keys?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I am new in PHP and love to learn it.
I want to merge two or more arrays having same keys only. And neglect the arrays whose keys are not in both the Arrays. Like

Here is the First Array :

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [111] => 36265
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [222] => 36265
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [333] => 36265
    )
)
```

and Second Array as :

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [444] => 36265
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [555] => 36265
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [666] => 36265
    )
)
```

And i want my result to be as :

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [111] => 36265
        [444] => 36265
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [222] => 36265
        [555] => 36265
    )

)
```

Neglecting the rest Array with key [3] & [4]....

So Please anyone tell me how to get this. I try out "array_merge_recursive()" but this one displays all keys.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean you want to merge by index and not by key right? That i see from your example. Because the keys are different in your example, but the index [1] and [2] is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to loop over one of the arrays, check for the existence of the current key in the other array, if it exists, merge them, eg:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
  if (array_key_exists($key, $array2)) {
    $output[$key] = $value + $array2[$key];
  } 
}
```

#### [Here's a demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vf3Dq3)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [`array_intersect_key`](https://www.php.net/array_intersect_key).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a foreacah loop and create a new one. While in this loop you can use one of the arrays keys to match them both. Consider this example:

```
 $array1 = array( 1 => array(111 => 36265), 2 => array(222 => 36265), 3 => array(333 => 36265), ); $array2 = array( 1 => array(444 => 36265), 2 => array(555 => 36265), 4 => array(666 => 36265), );

$new_array = array();
foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
    if(isset($array2[$key])) {
        $new_array[$key][key($array1[$key])] = reset($array1[$key]);
        $new_array[$key][key($array2[$key])] = reset($array2[$key]);
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Should yield something like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [111] => 36265
            [444] => 36265
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [222] => 36265
            [555] => 36265
        )

)
```